Sonarqube not showing coverage percentage
I have set up a React.js sample project to try out sonarqube with Github actions. I have tried multiple ways to get the coverage % but everytime it is showing No data about Coverage.
The Icov file path is set explicitly where it is the default path only. If I run the command npm run coverage the a coverage directory gets created in the local and Icov.info file also gets generated.
Repo :- https://github.com/shanbiswas/github-actions-cicd-react-app
PR :- https://github.com/shanbiswas/github-actions-cicd-react-app/pull/13

build.yml

name: Build
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
jobs:
  sonarcloud:
    name: SonarCloud
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0  # Shallow clones should be disabled for a better relevancy of analysis
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Test and coverage
        run: npm run coverage
      - name: SonarCloud Scan
        uses: SonarSource/sonarcloud-github-action@master
        with:
          args: >
            -Dsonar.organization=github-actions-react-cicd
            -Dsonar.projectKey=shanbiswas_github-actions-cicd-react-app
            -Dsonar.sources=src/
            -Dsonar.tests=src/
            -Dsonar.test.inclusions=src/*.test.js
            -Dsonar.exclusions=src/*.test.js
            -Dsonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=./coverage/lcov.info
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}


sonar-project.properties

sonar.projectKey=shanbiswas_github-actions-cicd-react-app
sonar.organization=github-actions-react-cicd

# This is the name and version displayed in the SonarCloud UI.
#sonar.projectName=github-actions-cicd-react-app
#sonar.projectVersion=1.0


# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Replace "\" by "/" on Windows.
sonar.sources=src/
sonar.tests=src/

sonar.exclusions=src/*.test.js
sonar.test.inclusions=src/*.test.js

sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=./coverage/lcov.info

# Encoding of the source code. Default is default system encoding
#sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8


package.json

{
  "name": "github-actions-cicd-react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:ci": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "coverage": "jest --coverage"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}

